# Django translation returning the same strings

Tags: django, internationalization, gettext

I am setting up a new small project to try i18n in Django 1.4.3 (English and Dutch). But I think I'm missing a step, as it is not translating the strings.

Who can tell me what I need to do to get the translated strings? How can I debug?

**settings.py**:

```
gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
  ('nl', gettext('Dutch')),
  ('en', gettext('English')),
)

LOCALE_PATH= (
  '/var/www/test/locale',
)
# django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware is also included @ MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES
```

The **urls.py** file:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    #home
    url(r'^$','bday.views.home',name="index"),
)
```

**views.py** in project:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
def home(request):
  text=_("Welcome!")
  return HttpResponse("LANG[{}], TEXT[{}]".format( request.LANGUAGE_CODE, text ) )
```

/var/www/test/locale/**nl**/LC_MESSAGES/django.**po**

```
#: bday/views.py:16
msgid "Welcome!"
msgstr "Welkon in Nederlands"
```

/var/www/test/locale/**en**/LC_MESSAGES/django.**po**

```
#: bday/views.py:16
msgid "Welcome!"
msgstr "Welcome in English"
```

The messages do get compiled, I get:

```
./manage.py compilemessages
processing file django.po in /var/www/test/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES
processing file django.po in /var/www/test/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES
```

But in my app, I'm getting:

```
$ curl "http://www.host.com:8000/nl/" 
LANG[nl], TEXT[Welcome!]
$ curl "http://www.host.com:8000/en/" 
LANG[en], TEXT[Welcome!]
```

Comment: You need to set the actuall language with django.utils.translation.activate

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think this is done automatically by the urlconf. Adding it to the code (directly after the imports) doesn't change anything.

Comment: $ mv locale{,old}/

$ mkdir locale

$ ./manage.py makemessages -l en

$ vim locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po

$ ./manage.py compilemessages

No change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set [LOCALE_PATHS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#locale-paths) in `settings.py`?

This only applies if you have translations in project directory.

Comment: Thanks. I set LOCALE_PATH instead of LOCALE_PATHS. Stupid typo. Thanks for the help.